# PreloadJS - Load a spritesheet on version 0.6.2

Tags: cordova, createjs, sprite-sheet, preloadjs

I have some troubles with the new version of PreloadJS (0.6.2) on Android.
The problem is that I want to load a spritesheet json using this:

```
{ "src": "textures/1x/spriteSheetDefault.json", "id": "spriteSheetDefault-json", "type": "spritesheet" }
```

And It's not working!
If I remove the `"type": "spritesheet"` it works but doesn't load the way I want.
If I rollback to version 0.6.1 it works normally.

Has anyone had the same problem?

**EDIT:** It happens on desktop too.

Comment: Does your issue happen on desktop as well, or is it limited to Android?

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Comment: I am sorry but I check it again and I found out that happens on desktop too!

Comment: @brunok8, Can you post a full example that demos this issue? I can't reproduce this problem (using PreloadJS 0.6.2). Thanks!